# Magento online customers last URL rewrite

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I'm running Magento CE 1.6.2.0.

Magento's Online Customers feature is great. Only problem is the "Last URL" column could be more helpful by displaying a rewrite (if one exists).

I changed `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/Grid/Renderer/Url.php` from this:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
}
```

to this:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $lastUrl = htmlspecialchars($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));

    $lastUrlRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
        ->setStoreId(1)
        ->loadByRequestPath($lastUrl);

    $url = ($lastUrlRewrite) ? $lastUrlRewrite : $lastUrl;

    return $url;
}
```

The `StoreId` is correct but the output remains empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `loadByRequestPath()` method returns a `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` object, not a string.  You probably want to do this:

```
 $url = ($lastUrlRewrite->getId()) ? $lastUrlRewrite->getTargetPath() : $lastUrl;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If I set `return print_r($lastUrlRewrite);` I can see that the `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` object contains all null values (although there are some keys), so I suspect the problem is further up in my code.

Comment: Ya so in that case it sounds like there isn't a URL rewrite match for the url in question?  I'd get a debugger setup if I were you, will really help you step through the logic.

Comment: Problem is there are URLs that display which I know for a fact have verified and working rewrites...